# Configuring a reverse proxy in Apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4, sles11

I have upgraded `apache2` from 2.2.x to 2.4.23 during a failover migration.

When I tried to start my server with my previous configuration I couldn't get it to work.

My default host contains `Proxy` directives that lead to applications installed on the production server on different ports. So the Apache server basically offers a gateway to several applications each one installed on its own (Tomcat) runtime.

Within the `default-server.conf` I had

```
ProxyPass        "/jira" "http://localhost:9090/jira" connectiontimeout=5 timeout=30
ProxyPassReverse "/jira" "http://localhost:9090/jira"


ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass        /artifactory http://localhost:8081/artifactory
ProxyPassReverse /artifactory http://localhost:8081/artifactory
```

Apache will fail starting at the very first of these lines

```
Starting httpd (prefork) AH00526: Syntax error on line 202 of /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/default.include:
Invalid command 'ProxyPass', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

The command line was:
/usr/sbin/httpd-prefork -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

But mod proxy is enabled

From `/etc/sysconfig/apache2`:

```
APACHE_MODULES="actions alias auth_basic authn_file authz_host authz_groupfile authz_user authn_dbm autoindex cgi dir env expires include log_config mime negotiation setenvif ssl suexec userdir php5 reqtimeout  mod_dav mod_dav_fs mod_proxy authz_core"
```

Also, running `apache2ctl -M` to show modules returns this interesting gem

```
# apache2ctl -M
AH00526: Syntax error on line 202 of /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/default.include:
Invalid ProxyPass|ProxyPassMatch parameter. Parameter must be in the form 'key=value'.
```

How can I make my reverse proxy work again? OS is SLES 11 SP4

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable mod_proxy_http; please check https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyrequests .

Comment: It would appear mod_proxy is actually enabled.